# How to mock superclass call with EasyMock

Tags: java, junit4, easymock

Is there a way to mock a superclass call with EasyMock?

I want to test something like this.

```
public class A extends B {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        String bClassName = super.getName();
        String aClassName = "Class A";
        return aClassName + " -> " + bClassName;
    }
}

public class B {

    public String getName(){
        return "Class B";
    }

}

public class ATest extends TestCase {

    private A a = new A();

    @Test
    public void testGetName() {
        A partialMockA = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(A.class)
                .addMockedMethod("getName").createMock();

//      expect b.getName();

        replay(partialMockA);
        String name = partialMockA.getName();
        assertEquals("Class A -> <MockResult>", name);
        verify(partialMockA);
    }
}
```

I'm playing around with partialMocks, but i think that is not the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No. Not with EasyMock. You will need to add PowerMock to do it. For instance, you can suppress the super call (from as far as I know but I don't have an example at hand sadly).